# Defining a function that takes a user input variable as an argument without repeating question to user

Tags: function, validation, arguments

I am learning python and the current task is user defined functions.  My instruction is to create a variable called 'city_flight' that requests input from a user as to which city they want to fly to. It must also give the user options of cities to fly to.  And I must remember that there will be different prices attached to the different cities.
Then I must create a function called 'plane_cost' that takes city_flight as an argument and returns the cost of the flight which I must then use later in the code to calculate the total cost of the holiday.  The tip is to use if else statements in the plane_cost function to determine which city to fly to.

I am stumped.  My two main difficulties are that I can't seem to get a way not to ask the user for the same input twice.  Then I'm struggling to get it to work when user inputs something not in the options function.  Then I keep getting this weird thing where it will repeat the loop even though user has given correct input.

I have tried multiple things.  I have tried making the options a dictionary as initially I was struggling to get the value returned as an integer so I can use it in the rest of my code. This is my latest attempt:

`# Determine flight cost``
# Define variable that I can use with the if/else statements in the function for user to choose       from
def options():
print("The cities you can fly to are:")
print("Tokyo")
print("Madrid")
print("Dubai")
print("q = quit")

```
# Define a function that will take 'city_flight' variable and if else statements to determine cost of flight
```

```
    def plane_cost(city):
        city = "x"
        options()
        while city != "q":
            city = input("Please enter your city: ").lower()
            if city == "tokyo":
                return 1000
                options()
            elif city == "madrid":
                return 800
                options()
            elif city == "dubai":
                return 1200
                options()
            elif city == "q":
                print("")
            else:
                print("Unrecognized option.")
                options()
```

city_flight = input("Please enter the city you are flying to: ")
plane_cost(city_flight)
print(plane_cost(city_flight))
print(type(plane_cost(city_flight)))